# Get credentials in pipeline script

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using "Parameterized Build" and in particular "Credentials parameter"
[image]

In my Pipeline script how can I access to the username and password of TEST variable?

```
timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') { 
  node('jenkins-slave1') {
      ....
      sh 'echo ${TEST_USER}'
      sh 'echo ${TEST_PASSWORD}'
  }
}
```

I know that I can use inside the script

```
  withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: '5994c63b-ee86-4ef1-b28a-ee2236662226', 
           passwordVariable: 'TEST_PASSWORD', 
           usernameVariable: 'TEST_USER']]) {
             sh "echo ${env.TEST_USER}"
             sh "echo ${env.TEST_PASSWORD}"
  }
```

but I need to provide this choice to the final user running the job

Thanks!
Riccardo

Comment: What choice do you have in mind? You want them to select which credentails defined in jenkins they can use? Or allow them to enter username and password?

Comment: The first one. The user selects a pair before starting the job